# Unix - Bash code to run PING and SNMP from a file to a file *EDIT*

Tags: bash, unix, sh, ping, snmp

I'm trying to run a batch on bash to run ping and snmp from a csv and to store the results either responding or not on a notepad.

The file identifies the single column CSV with each server, and run ping, review, run snmp, review, stores and moves each file

The connection to the server is working but the script keeps failing at the missing line #26 under the error /usr/tmp/testing_script.sh: line 26: syntax error: unexpected end of file

---

Update from here. I've done some improves but still struggling with this one.
Here is where I've come so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
nombrep="pin_"$hostname
nombres="smmp_"$hostname
file="/usr/tmp/devices.csv"
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
cat "$file" | while read col1; do 
{
        DNSRes=0
        ping -q -c3 $col1 >> /usr/tmp/pin
        grep " 100% packet loss" /usr/tmp/pin
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo $col1"," >> /usr/tmp/pin_fail
                hostname >> /usr/tmp/pin_fail
                echo -e "\n" >> /usr/tmp/pin_fail
        fi
        grep "unknown host" /usr/tmp/pin
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo $col1"," >> /usr/tmp/No_DNS
                echo -e "\n" >> /usr/tmp/No_DNS
        fi
        if [ -e /usr/tmp/pin ]; then
                rm /usr/tmp/pin
        fi
        if [ $DNSRes -eq 0 ]; then
            snmp ********** $col1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 >> /usr/tmp/smmp
            grep "No response" /usr/tmp/smmp
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo -n $col1"," >> /usr/tmp/smmp_fail
                    hostname >> /usr/tmp/smmp_fail
                    echo -e "\n" >> /usr/tmp/smmp_fail
            fi
        fi
        if [ -e /usr/tmp/smmp ]; then
                rm -r /usr/tmp/smmp
        fi
}
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
if [ -e /usr/tmp/pin__fail ]; then
        mv /usr/tmp/pin_fail > /usr/tmp/$nombrep
fi
if [ -e /usr/tmp/smmp_fail ]; then
        mv /usr/tmp/smmp_fail > /usr/tmp/$nombres
fi
exit 0;
```

Also I'm adding the cmd file from where I'm currently running this bash script which is on a windows-putty interface

```
echo on

pscp.exe -p -q -batch -pw #password# c:\logs\devices_gtn.csv #username#@host:/usr/tmp
pscp.exe -p -q -batch -pw #password# c:\logs\testing_script.sh #username#@host:/usr/tmp
plink.exe -pw #password# #username#@host "chmod 777 /usr/tmp/testing_script.sh"
plink.exe -pw #password# #username#@host "chmod 777 /usr/tmp/devices.csv"
plink.exe -v -pw #password# #username#@host "bash /usr/tmp/testing_script.sh"

del /f /q c:\logs\No_DNS.csv

pscp.exe -p -q -batch -pw #password# #username#@host:/usr/tmp/pin* c:\logs\
pscp.exe -p -q -batch -pw #password# #username#@host:/usr/tmp/smmp* c:\logs\
pscp.exe -p -q -batch -pw #password# #username#@host:/usr/tmp/No_DNS* c:\logs\No_DNS.csv
plink.exe -pw #password# #username#@host "rm -r /usr/tmp/pin*"
plink.exe -pw #password# #username#@host "rm -r /usr/tmp/smmp*"
plink.exe -pw #password# #username#@host "rm -r /usr/tmp/devices*"
plink.exe -pw #password# #username#@host "rm -r /usr/tmp/testing*"
plink.exe -pw #password# #username#@host "rm -r /usr/tmp/No_DNS*"

if not exist results (
    md results)
if exist c:\logs\results\snmp_results.csv (
    del /f /q c:\logs\results\snmp_results.csv)
if exist c:\logs\results\ping_results.csv (
    del /f /q c:\logs\results\ping_results.csv)

if exist pin_host (
    type pin_host >> c:\logs\results\ping_results.csv)
if not exist c:\logs\results\ping_results.csv (
    echo "ping success" >> c:\logs\results\ping_results.csv)

if not exist results (
    md results)
if exist smmp_host (
    type smmp_host >> c:\logs\results\snmp_results.csv)
if not exist c:\logs\results\snmp_results.csv (
    echo "snmp success" >> c:\logs\results\snmp_results.csv)

if exist c:\logs\No_DNS.csv (
    start notepade.exe "c:\logs\results\No_DNS.csv")

start notepad.exe "c:\logs\results\ping_results.csv"
start notepad.exe "c:\logs\results\snmp_results.csv"

del /f /q c:\logs\smmp*.*
del /f /q c:\logs\pin*.*

exit
```

As it is, is not working. The code seems to be fine, since when I manually do it from the server itself, it partially works, except for some issues retrieving information from the csv file.

So I'm going blind on this one, as I don't know what is failing.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: That's a convoluted syntax error, try changing `[$?` to `[ $?` and likewise occurrences of `0]` to `0 ]`.  The square brackets are tokens and need to be followed/preceded by a space to be interpreted properly.

Comment: Adding a space after or before the backets doesn't seems to be working. Keeps coming back with syntax error regarding line #26

Comment: `while read $col1` should probably be `while read col1`.

Comment: Yes, I did tried both early today but still not managing to figure it out. The error keeps coming no matter what

Comment: now you have to roll up your sleeves and comment out bottom 1/2 of script. Run it, Do you still get the error message? If yes, comment out the bottom 3/4's of script. If No error message, then uncomment 1/2 of what is commented (allowing for `while .. done`, `if..then ..fi` blocks (and other multi-line syntaxs) to be completely commented or uncommented).  
So you have to comment out code, see if the problem goes away, and then uncomment a little more, seeing which set of lines generate the error.

Comment: Incidentally, it's always a good idea to surround variables for `echo`ing with dbl-qts. i.e `echo -n "$col1," ... ` OR `echo -n "${col1},"` just in case. Also, all of the comments are correct. The script will never work with `[$? -eq 0]`. Same for `while read $col1`. It should be `while read col1`. And... It's not clear from your comments if you're just testing these recommendations. Change you code, and edit so we can see your best work. Good luck.

Comment: Try this first, before commenting out blocks of code. Add `set -vx` on line 2 of your script. Make sure variable values are working the way you expect. And quote all variable name usage. A space in your $hostname might be messing things up. (or any of the other variables). Good luck2!

Comment: Thanks all for the help given. Regarding shellter comments, I did tried everything recommended. But I'm still unable to find the way out of this nightmare. Commenting portions of the code doesn't seem to be working, this is something related with the end "done" and some missing information in the middle from my side.

Comment: one more thing, try changing top line to `#!/bin/bash -n`. This should do a basic syntax check, and may emit a different error message that gives you a better clue. If that fails. Then I would start over again, and just get the while loop to work, i.e. `cat "$file" | while read col1; do echo "col1=$col1"; done`. Then add the first `grep` .  Etc etc. You are very close. There is nothing obvious that would be generating this error. If you created your file on Windows and  moved it to Unix/Linux, use `dos2unix myScript.sh` to make it usable in Unix/Linux. Updt your quest. with best/current code!

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `-n` after you test with it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few weird things in you script. You don't do anything with the variable `DNSRes=0` to give it another value. I'd also suggest some more redirecting the output of one command into the other. 
Further, from the manual page of ping:

```
 The ping utility exits with one of the following values:
 0       At least one response was heard from the specified host.
 2       The transmission was successful but no responses were received.
 any other value
         An error occurred.  These values are defined in <sysexits.h>.
```

You check for exitcode 0 to conclude that the ping fails and put the hostname of the pinging system (not the pinged system) in `/usr/tmp/pin_fail`.

But let's analyse (a part) of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
nombrep="pin_"$hostname
nombres="smmp_"$hostname
```

I should write that as:

```
#!/bin/bash
nombrep="pin_${hostname}"
nombres="smmp_${hostname}"
```

Next part:

```
file="/usr/tmp/devices.csv"
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
cat "$file" | while read col1; do
```

This seems fair enough.

```
{
    DNSRes=0
```

You set the `DNSRes=0` here, never change it further in the script and check it if it is still zero.

```
    ping -q -c3 $col1 >> /usr/tmp/pin
    grep " 100% packet loss" /usr/tmp/pin
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo $col1"," >> /usr/tmp/pin_fail
            hostname >> /usr/tmp/pin_fail
            echo -e "\n" >> /usr/tmp/pin_fail
    fi
```

I should write this as:

```
if ping -q -c3 $col1 | grep -q "100% packet loss"
then
     echo "${col1},$(hostname)" >> /usr/tmp/pin_fail
fi
```

Or, when you want the honor the suggestions of the `ping` manual page:

```
ping -q -c3 ${col1}
exitcode_ping=$?
if [ ${exitcode_ping} -eq 2 ]
then 
     echo "${col1},$(hostname)" >> /usr/tmp/pin_fail
fi
```

Well, you can use the `${exitcode_ping}` variable for further checking. I'll leave that part to you.